# Angular(version 4) not accepting "required" attribute

Tags: html, angular

While creating **template driven** forms in Angular(4.0v) if 
"required" attribute is used in input tag it does nothing i.e. the form loads normally without any kind of error in console and nor does it throws error message like "Fill in this field" when one click's *submit* *button*.

Even [form-validation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html) link from Angular documents shows that it accepts "required" attribute in template driven approach than what's wrong with mine?

```
<h1>Template Driven</h1>
<form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(f)" #f = "ngForm">
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="username"
             placeholder="Username"
             ngModel 
             name = "username"
             required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="email"
             placeholder="E-mail"
             ngModel 
             name = "e-mail"
             required
             pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"
           class="form-control"
           id="password"
           placeholder="Password"
           ngModel 
           name = "password"
           required>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you don't have any error messages to show ;)

So the error messages for username should (could) look like the following, just like in the tutorial:

```
<div *ngIf="username.errors && (username.dirty || username.touched)">
   <div [hidden]="!username.errors.required">
      Username is required
   </div>
</div>
```

And then like in the tuto, you need the template reference for `ngModel`,
like so:

```
<input ..... #username="ngModel">
```

And then disable the button if the form is not valid:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: ok..... but I tried the same code in angular 2 and it threw an message of "**Please fill the field!**"

Comment: well you want error messages right? Or what is the problem?

Comment: also what is this **ngNativeValidate** ? because it worked(with a message of "Please fill the field!") after adding it to form tag

Comment: In angular 2 it worked (this very same template code) as the form threw the message of **Please fill the field!** when clicked on submit button

Comment: You mean that the browser threw the message, not the form? Yes, well that is a different case, you didn't really make that clear in your question. You wanted **browser** validation, **not** form validation. Yes then ngNativeValidate is the correct use. Please always try to make questions clear so that you get appropriate answers.